# jquery how to add values from multiple nodes with a class, and output final value?

Tags: jquery, sum, addition

http://jsfiddle.net/7Upk7/

I am simply trying to some how add multiple values, and append the answer in a specified node.

So for example I am trying to add all the values of `td.add-hour` and output the answer in `td.sum-hour`

```
$('td.add-hour').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
});

$('td.sum-hour').html(sum);​
```

But I'm really struggling to find an simple working solution. Can anyone please advise to a jquery solution.

Please see fiddle below with one of many attempts.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Upk7/

Thanks in advance. Josh

Comment: Like that? http://jsfiddle.net/7Upk7/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

`sum` is never initialized.  Before anything else, write: `var sum = 0;`

`.val` is to get the value of inputs.  You want to use `.text()`.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/7Upk7/2/

Comment: Awesome thanks dude! Fixed some fundamental issues there for me!